# Why won't Oracle use the spatial index when JOINing tables? (Or: Why is my query with a spatial JOIN so slow in Oracle?)

Tags: oracle, index, spatial

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_DATA (
  MY_DATA_ID NUMBER(38,0) PRIMARY KEY,
  GEOM SDO_GEOMETRY
);
```

I've set its SDO metadata and created a spatial index:

```
INSERT INTO USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA (TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, SRID, DIMINFO)
VALUES ('MY_DATA', 'GEOM', 4326, MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ARRAY(MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('X',-180.0000,180.0000,0.00000000001),MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('Y',-90.0000,90,0.00000000001)));

CREATE INDEX SPIX_MY_DATA ON MY_DATA (GEOM) INDEXTYPE IS MDSYS.SPATIAL_INDEX;
```

The table has about 150,000 rows.

I need to find rows where the geometries intersect one specific row. This seems like a simple enough task. All it takes is a `JOIN` and a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT /*+ INDEX(MD2 SPIX_MY_DATA)*/
    MD2.MY_DATA_ID
FROM MY_DATA MD1
JOIN MY_DATA MD2 ON SDO_RELATE(MD1.GEOM, MD2.GEOM, 'mask=ANYINTERACT') = 'TRUE'
WHERE MD1.MY_DATA_ID = 143668 AND MD2.MY_DATA_ID != 143668
```

But this query is *very* slow. It takes over 85 seconds to fetch only 8 related rows. We can see from the query plan that it's not using the spatial index, in spite of the index hint:

```
Plan hash value: 4008712617

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name          | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |               |   379 |  9854 |  1390   (1)| 00:00:17 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                |               |   379 |  9854 |  1390   (1)| 00:00:17 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| MY_DATA       |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | SYS_C00755898 |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL          | MY_DATA       |   379 |  4927 |  1388   (1)| 00:00:17 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - access("MD1"."MY_DATA_ID"=143668)
   4 - filter("MD2"."MY_DATA_ID"<>143668 AND 
              "MDSYS"."SDO_RTREE_RELATE"("MD1"."GEOM","MD2"."GEOM",'mask=ANYINTERACT 
              querytype=window  ')='TRUE')
```

(Row 2 is MD1, and row 4 is MD2.)

I tried changing the hint to `/*+ INDEX(MY_DATA SPIX_MY_DATA)*/`, but this also had no effect. I've made sure my statistics are up to date.

How can I speed up this query? How can I get it to use the spatial index?

I'm currently using Oracle 11.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Behavior of `SDO_RELATE` and the query planner

[`SDO_RELATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_relate.htm#SPATL1039) will *only use the spatial index of the first parameter*. The documentation doesn't really say this explicitly, but it can be gleaned from some details there.

The documentation for the two geometry arguments say:

> `geometry1`: Specifies a geometry column in a table. **The column must be spatially indexed.** Data type is SDO_GEOMETRY.
>
> `geometry2` Specifies either a geometry from a table or a **transient instance of a geometry**. (Specified using a bind variable or SDO_GEOMETRY constructor.) Data type is SDO_GEOMETRY.

(emphasis mine)

This suggests very strongly that `SDO_RELATE` is designed specifically to use the spatial index on its *first argument*. However, since you have a primary key filter on `MD1` in your `WHERE` clause, the planner rightly concludes that using the primary key index will be faster that using the spatial index on `MD1`. It *never considers* reversing the arguments to the function, and since `SDO_RELATE` uses the index on the first argument instead of the second, it never considers actually using the spatial index.

[`SDO_FILTER`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_filter.htm) behaves the same way, as far as I can tell.

### The solution

The answer is as simple as it is unintuitive. Just switch the order of the arguments to `SDO_RELATE`:

```
SELECT
    MD2.MY_DATA_ID
FROM MY_DATA MD1
JOIN MY_DATA MD2 ON SDO_RELATE(MD2.GEOM, MD1.GEOM, 'mask=ANYINTERACT') = 'TRUE'
WHERE MD1.MY_DATA_ID = 143668 AND MD2.MY_DATA_ID != 143668
```

This causes it to use the spatial index now:

```
Plan hash value: 3780744499

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name          | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |               |  1487 | 38662 |   534   (1)| 00:00:07 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                |               |  1487 | 38662 |   534   (1)| 00:00:07 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| MY_DATA       |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | SYS_C00755898 |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| MY_DATA       |  1487 | 19331 |   534   (1)| 00:00:07 |
|*  5 |    DOMAIN INDEX              | SPIX_MY_DATA  |       |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - access("MD1"."MY_DATA_ID"=143668)
   4 - filter("MD2"."MY_DATA_ID"<>143668)
   5 - access("MDSYS"."SDO_RTREE_RELATE"("MD2"."GEOM","MD1"."GEOM",'mask=ANYINTERACT 
              querytype=window  ')='TRUE')
```

The query is now nearly instantaneous, running in about 50 milliseconds.

### Ignore the `ORDERED` hint part in the docs for cases like this

The documentation goes on to say later:

> `geometry2` can come from a table or be a transient SDO_GEOMETRY object, such as a bind variable or SDO_GEOMETRY constructor.
>
> - If the `geometry2` column is not spatially indexed, the operator indexes the query window in memory and performance is very good.
> - If two or more geometries from `geometry2` are passed to the operator, the ORDERED optimizer hint must be specified, and the table in `geometry2` must be specified first in the FROM clause.

From this, we might think we could also force the planner to use the index by putting `MD2` first in the list and specifying the `ORDERED` hint:

```
SELECT /*+ ORDERED INDEX(MD2 SPIX_MY_DATA)*/
    MD2.MY_DATA_ID
FROM MY_DATA MD2
JOIN MY_DATA MD1 ON SDO_RELATE(MD1.GEOM, MD2.GEOM, 'mask=ANYINTERACT') = 'TRUE'
WHERE MD1.MY_DATA_ID = 143668 AND MD2.MY_DATA_ID != 143668
```

which gives us a different execution plan:

```
Plan hash value: 3307523706

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                        | Name          | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                 |               |  1487 | 38662 | 14806   (1)| 00:02:58 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                    |               |  1487 | 38662 | 14806   (1)| 00:02:58 |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL              | MY_DATA       |   148K|  1887K|  4752   (1)| 00:00:58 |
|   3 |   BITMAP CONVERSION TO ROWIDS    |               |       |       |            |          |
|   4 |    BITMAP AND                    |               |       |       |            |          |
|   5 |     BITMAP CONVERSION FROM ROWIDS|               |       |       |            |          |
|   6 |      SORT ORDER BY               |               |       |       |            |          |
|*  7 |       DOMAIN INDEX               | SPIX_MY_DATA  |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   8 |     BITMAP CONVERSION FROM ROWIDS|               |       |       |            |          |
|*  9 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN            | SYS_C00755898 |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("MD2"."MY_DATA_ID"<>143668)
   7 - access("MDSYS"."SDO_RTREE_RELATE"("MD1"."GEOM","MD2"."GEOM",'mask=ANYINTERACT 
              querytype=window  ')='TRUE')
   9 - access("MD1"."MY_DATA_ID"=143668)
```

This does force the index to be used, but it's used in the wrong way. It's still doing a full table scan on `MD2`. Instead of filtering `MD2` by the lone geometry from `MD1`'s result set, it grabs almost all the rows in the table from `MD2` (note the 148K count on row 2 of the plan), performs two searches on `MD1` (one by the primary key and the other comparing *all the rows* in `MD2` using the spatial index), and bitmap-ands the result. This actually makes performance worse, doing a completely unnecessary scan on the spatial index and extra work comparing that scan to the primary key one.

As a general rule, you want to put the table with the smallest set of geometries (after other filters) first in your `FROM` clause and let it use the spatial index on the second table.

Just specifying the `ORDERED` hint on the original query does not change the plan from the original.